# Cosmos db partial update SQL api using Java SDK

Tags: java, azure, bigdata, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I know microsoft has released partial update for SQL api using Java SDK. I've gone through the document but wasn't sure how to approach step by step. If anyone has tried can someone help me how to do partial update for SQL api using Java SDK.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's right there in the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update-getting-started#java Is there something missing?

Comment: @MarkBrown - I've tried via java and able to update in SQL API. But, would like to know 

1. The documents shows how to update single , multiple upsert. Is there anyway we can add list of values from a file to be updated in SQL api using add operation?
2.  if this can be implemented via Scala-Spark as well?

Comment: You can patch multiple documents in the same logical partition using Transactional Batch in Java SDK. Java has file/stream io operations so reading values from a file is possible. Have never tried to do what you're suggesting. Also have no experience using Scala so can't help you there.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly I would like to suggest you to go through the release notes and resources, so that we will get an idea about a path of how can we use.
So here the new is that Sync and Async API combined into one Artifact and the performance was increase when we compare with v2 versions ( For both Sync and Async).
[Download](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-cosmos) SDK from Maven Repository to get started with.

Below are few steps to build an app with Cosmos DB:

1. Create Database account
2. In Data Explorer add a new container
3. Add Sample data in Items under Tasks, below is the sample one.

   ```
    {
    "id": "1",
    "category": "personal",
    "name": "groceries",
    "description": "Pick up apples and strawberries.",
    "isComplete": false
   }
   ```
4. Then query the data.
5. Clone the sample application.

Also below are few commands to run the app:

```
mvn package
mvn exec:java@SYNCASYNCMODE -DACCOUNT_HOST=YOUR_COSMOS_DB_HOSTNAME -DACCOUNT_KEY=YOUR_COSMOS_DB_MASTER_KEY
```

Kindly go through these links from MS Docs to get more information about [Patch API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update) Feature, [Release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-sdk-java-v4) and resources, [AzureJavaSDK](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-cosmos/latest/index.html) for CosmosDB Client, [Migrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/migrate-java-v4-sdk?tabs=java-v4-async) your app to SDKV4

Comment: You are essentially sharing content from the docs; this isn't an answer. Also, the OP isn't asking about maven, or creating databases/collections, or sample documents.